# Australia phone number validation is not working in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to set Australia's phone number validation using regExp. The condition is

1. it should be number
2. should start with 04
3. should be 10 digits

But my condition is not working. Can anyone help?

```
 this.shippingForm = this.fb.group({
 phone: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('(04)[0-9]{10}')]]
 }
```

Comment: I searched for "australia phone number regex" and found a bunch like [this one](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2014/08/regular-expression-for-validating-australian-phone-numbers-including-landline-and-mobile/).

Comment: It should be 10 digits in total, or 10 digits after 04?  I tried 040123456789 with your regex in https://regex101.com/ and it seemed to match.

Comment: including 04, it should be 10 digit

Comment: can you send the regExp for this conditon?

Comment: Just change your 10 to an 8 then.  It currently says there must be "04" and THEN 10 digits which means a total of 12.  Try `(04)[0-9]{8}`

Comment: Just to tell you, only mobile phone numbers (and all mobile numbers) start with "04". The landline numbers start with 02, 03, 05, etc mostly (but but not always) depending on which state they are in. Sometimes people put "614" instead of "04" to make the number internationally compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression. I've tested [here](http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/) `^04[0-9]{8}`

Answer (score 0):

Your regular exp says 04(2 digits) [0-9]{10}(10 digits) that is 12 digits.
So change it to `(04)[0-9]{08}` which is 2+8 = 10 digits

Answer (score 0):

Try using this one

```
^04[0-9]{8}$
```